# How do I choose one TEMPLATE in ZK DataBinding?

Tags: java, mvvm, binding, zk

I have four templates for my grid, but I could not in any way change the grid's template by an event (for example, by clicking on hyperlink or button).
How do I select one template from others at runtime?

```
<grid id="dataGrid"  model="@bind(vm.taskDTOs) @template('newTaskTemplate')" width="100%">
    <columns id="dataGridColumns" />
    <template name="newTaskTemplate" var="newTask">
        <row>
            <label value="" />
            <label value="@bind(newTask.documentDTO.docTypeDTO.title)"/>
            <label value="@bind(newTask.documentDTO.docNumber)"/>
            <label value="@bind(newTask.documentDTO.docDateTime)"/>
            <label value="@bind(newTask.assignerID)"/>
            <label value="@bind(newTask.assignDateTime)"/>
            <label value="@bind(newTask.assignDateTime)"/>
            <label value="@bind(newTask.documentDTO.docTypeStateDTO.stateActionDTO.actionDTO.title)"/>
        </row>
    </template>

    <!--if="${templateStatus.value=='pendingTask'}"-->

    <template name="pendingTaskTemplate" var="pendingTask">
        <row>
            <label value="@bind(pendingTask.documentDTO.docTypeDTO.title)"/>
            <label value="@bind(pendingTask.documentDTO.docNumber)"/>
            <label value="@bind(pendingTask.documentDTO.docDateTime)"/>
            <label value="@bind(pendingTask.assignerID)"/>
            <label value="@bind(pendingTask.assignDateTime)"/>
            <label value="@bind(pendingTask.assignDateTime)"/>
            <label value="@bind(pendingTask.documentDTO.docTypeStateDTO.stateActionDTO.actionDTO.title)"/>
        </row>
    </template>

    <!--if="${templateStatus.value=='refferedTask'}"-->
    <template name="refferedTaskTemplate" var="RefferedTask">
        <row>
            <label value="@bind(RefferedTask.documentDTO.docTypeDTO.title)"/>
            <label value="@bind(RefferedTask.documentDTO.docNumber)"/>
            <label value="@bind(RefferedTask.documentDTO.docDateTime)"/>
            <label value="@bind(RefferedTask.assigneeID)"/>
            <label value="@bind(RefferedTask.assignDateTime)"/>
            <label value="@bind(RefferedTask.assignDateTime)"/>
            <label value="@bind(RefferedTask.catalogDTO.catalogTypeDTO.title)"/>
        </row>
    </template>

    <!--if="${templateStatus.value == 'allTask'}"-->

    <template name="allTaskTemplate" var="allTask">
        <row>
            <label value="" />
            <label value="@bind(allTask.documentDTO.docTypeDTO.title)"/>
            <label value="@bind(allTask.documentDTO.docNumber)"/>
            <label value="@bind(allTask.documentDTO.docDateTime)"/>
            <label value="@bind(allTask.assignerID)"/>
            <label value="@bind(allTask.assigneeID)"/>
            <label value="@bind(allTask.assignDateTime)"/>
            <label value="@bind(allTask.assignDateTime)"/>
            <label value="@bind(allTask.assignDateTime)"/>
            <label value="@bind(allTask.assignDateTime)"/>
            <label value="@bind(allTask.documentDTO.docTypeStateDTO.stateActionDTO.actionDTO.title)"/>
            <label value="@bind(allTask.catalogDTO.catalogTypeDTO.title)"/>
        </row>
    </template>
</grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a "dynamic template". Please refer to *[Children Binding, Combine with Dynamic Template](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVVM/Data_Binding/Children_Binding#Combine_with_Dynamic_Template)*.

In your case, you can store the template name as a ViewModel's property, and bind to it like `@template(vm.templateName)`.

Then change the property `vm.templateName` at run-time to switch the Grid's template.